# I want to add element at the end of list in scala. How can i achieve it?

Tags: list, scala

Lets take an example where store is my class.

```
class store(val a:Int) { }
```

In the code i want to create a list of store.

```
 val list : List[store] = new List[store]()
```

How can i add a store in the same list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it's usually a good idea to capitalize your class names.

```
scala> class Store(val a:Int) { }
defined class Store

scala> val list : List[Store] = List.empty
list: List[Store] = List()

scala> val newList = new Store(4) :: list
newList: List[Store] = List(Store@243306de)
```

Your list is, by default, immutable so you'll have a new list every time an element is added.

```
scala> val newerList = new Store(71) :: newList
newerList: List[Store] = List(Store@30f57af0, Store@243306de)
```

**ADDENDUM**

If you need a mutable list (not usually recommended) you could try the following.

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList

scala> val myList: MutableList[Store] = MutableList.empty
myList: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Store] = MutableList()

scala> myList += new Store(56)
res322: myList.type = MutableList(Store@6421614e)

scala> myList += new Store(29)
res323: myList.type = MutableList(Store@6421614e, Store@85b26)

scala> myList += new Store(11)
res324: myList.type = MutableList(Store@6421614e, Store@85b26, Store@5d2f7883)
```

Mutable variables are considered poor style and an impediment to proper Functional Programming.

Comment: How can i add to same list and not create a new one whenever i add a store.

Comment: You can't add to an immutable list. Use a mutable list such as `ListBuffer`

Comment: See the addendum to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

To add element to the beginning of the list use `::` :

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3)

val l1 = 5 :: l // List(5, 1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
val l1 = l.::(5)
```

To add element to the end of the list use `:+` :

```
val l2 = l :+ 5 // List(1, 2, 3, 5)
```

So, to add `store` object *to the end* of the list (though it is not efficient), write this:

```
val s = new Store(1)

val newList = list :+ s // list is immutable
```